# Wildcard SSL mapping multiple Azure App Service apps

Tags: azure, ssl, configuration, azure-web-app-service, wildcard-subdomain

I have domain.com, a.domain.com, b.domain.com, and c.domain.com to be mapped to x.azurewebsites.net a.azurewebsites.net, a.azurewebsites.net and a.azurewebsites.net

I am able to set the following

`A record pointing to IP address of x.azurewebsites.net` and

```
CNAME www.domain.com pointed to x.azurewebsites.net
```

And update SSL, it works for https works for domain.com and www.domain.com

When I am setting up a.domain.com to a.azurewebsites.net

I cannot set A record, So I set CNAME

```
CNAME a.domain.com pointed to a.azurewebsites.net
```

How can I fix DNS configuration for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you have successfully mapped a subdomain (www.domain.com) with a CNAME record and a root domain (domain.com) with an A record to your one Azure Web App, and you want to configure the similar mapping for another Azure Web App. AFAIK, you could not map the same root domain to multiple hostnames or IPs, at this point, it does not know which Azure Web Apps are you trying to access. You could only map subdomains 
 (app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com) to the related azure web apps (app1.azurewebsites.net, app2.azurewebsites.net). More details about mapping the custom DNS name to your Azure Web Apps, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Answer (score 1):

Setting a.domain.com pointed to a.azurewebsites.net though was enough, I had to do it multiple times (no idea why). Once that is done, I was also able to setup SSL for that once I was able to see a.domain.com and now redirection is working.

After lot of trial and errors, got the steps jolted at https://medium.com/pooran-tech/wildcard-domain-ssl-configuring-in-azure-app-services-e1cefc8d75bf